# how to override operator ++ to return a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I write a Linked list and I'm trying to override the ++ operator.
I wrote the Linked list as a class object and the nodes as a struct that contains data and two pointers (next and previous nodes).
every time  I call the ++ operator after the node pointer I want to return a pointer to the next
so instead of writing `ptr = ptr->next` I want to write `ptr++`.

My header code:

```
class MyLinkedList
{
private:

    struct Node
    {
        double data;
        Node *next = NULL;
        Node *previous = NULL;

        Node& operator ++ ();
    }

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
}
```

cpp code:

```
MyLinkedList::Node& MyLinkedList::Node::operator ++ ()
{
    *this = *next;
    return *this;
}
```

e.g

```
MyLinkedList a;
...
Node *ptr = a.tail;
while (ptr != NULL)
{
    ptr++; //ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can override `++` for pointers. Currently you are overriding it for `Node`, not `Node*`. `ptr++` already has a well-defined meaning - it means `ptr = ptr + 1;`.

Comment: You might want to write your own iterator class, which acts like a pointer but isn't. Then you can define `NodeIterator::operator ++`.

Answer (score 2):

Make the pointer a class:

```
// This is an example
class NodePtr
{
    Node *m_node;
public:
    NodePtr() : m_node(nullptr) {}
    NodePtr(Node * node) : m_node(node) {}

    bool IsNull() const { return m_node == null; }
    Node& GetNode() { assert(m_node); return *m_node; }
    NodePtr& operator ++ () { assert(m_node); m_node = m_node->next; return *this;}
};
```